# Javascript Object destructuring and default parameters combined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Today I came across the following syntax which I didn't recognize:

```js
const createUser = ({
  age = 1,
  name = 'Anonymous',
}) => ({
  age,
  name,
});


const defaultP = createUser({
  age: 5
});
console.log(defaultP);
```

I think it uses Object destructuring and default parameters in order to set defaults of the object which is send as an argument.

The syntax threw me a bit off because normally I see object destructuring only in the following manner:

```js
let obj = {
   prop1: 1
}

const {prop1} = obj;

console.log(prop1);
```

### Question:

How does this syntax work exactly?

Comment: Those are just default values for destructured properties. Works the same way as `(x = 1) => {}`, just nested within another object: `({a = 1}) => {}`.

Comment: Okay after looking at it a bit more and asking this question I think I got it now but it looked pretty strange in the beginning

Comment: maybe you have a look here: [object property assignment pattern [YDKJS: ES6 & Beyond]](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#object-property-assignment-pattern)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That syntax indeed uses [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) in order to extract default values from the parameter object. There are some examples in [the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variables_names_and_providing_default_values) that helps us understand the trick, check this out:

```
var {a = 10, b = 5} = {a: 3};
console.log(a); // 3
console.log(b); // 5
```

A possible disadvantage of your example is that the `createUser` method ignores all other values of the parameter object and **always** returns an object that contains only `age` and `name`. If you want to make this more flexible, we could use `Object.assign()` like this:

```
const createUser = (o) => Object.assign({ age: 1, name: 'Anonymous' }, o);
```

In this case, the user created will be an object that merges the parameter object with the default values. Note now that the default values are in the method body. With this method we can create users that contain other properties, example:

```
const superman = createUser({ name: 'Superman', type: 'superhero' });
console.log(superman);
// output: {age: 1, name: "Superman", type: "Superhero"}
```

Comment: Could you explain please, in this example `var {a = 10, b = 5} = {a: 3}` how javascript sets value of `b` to 5? Whether it sets `b` to `undefined` first and then assigns `b=5` or does it work in another way?
How does it work under the hood?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is using both `Object Destructuring` and `default function props`.

```
const createUser = ({
  age = 1,
  name = 'Anonymous',
}) => ({
  age,
  name,
});
```

Here function `createUser` is accepting single argument of type `Object`. Function is returing same object, if you have both object properties defined in your argument, then it will return your passed object. Otherwise it will replace it with default values, which are `1` and `Anonymous` respectively.

You can further read about it here:

https://wesbos.com/destructuring-renaming/

https://wesbos.com/destructuring-default-values/

Answer (score 1):

If you use babel and transpile your code to ES5, it will look like this:

```
function createUser(params) {
  return {
    age: typeof params.age === 'undefined' ? 1 : params.age,
    name: typeof params.name === 'undefined' ? 'Anonymous' : params.name,
  };
}
```

---

Just a note: default values for function arguments works the same way:

```
const multiply = (a, optionalB) => {
  const b = typeof optionalB !== 'undefined' ? optionalB : 2;
  return a * b;
}
```

Is same as:

```
const multiply = (a, b = 2) => {
  return a * b;
}
```

It increases a readability, mostly in cases when argument is used several times.